# Django hidden input set dynamic value (depending on link)?

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a Django form with one of the hidden input value set dynamically.

I have 5 links -> `Class 1, Class 2, Class 3, Class 4, Class 5`

All of them redirects to the same form.

But if the person clicks say 'Class 1' the value of hidden input value will be 'Class 1' and so on.

I am pretty new to Django. So, any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need this in the form itself? Isn't it already in the URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to save the form data in database along with the link from which data came.

Comment: That didn't really answer the question. It's easy to add data to the object when you save: `obj = form.save(commit=False); obj.foo = whatever; obj.save()`.

Comment: I want that 'whatever' to be dynamic. i.e whatever is 'Class 1' for Class 1 link.

Comment: Yes. Get it from the URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to use a single view for all the links. Then how can i set it equal to Link name?

Comment: Same way you do with any other view; you capture a parameter in the URL, accept it as an argument to the view, and use it in that view.